# Selección de las columnas de un data.frame mediante un patrón

Tags: r

Intento seleccionar las columnas de un data.frame utilizando `subset()` según un patrón, hasta ahora he utilizado `select=c()` indicando como vector los nombres de las columnas, ahora necesito que las columnas seleccionadas contengan en su nombre un patrón.

```
colnames(df)
# "ID" "ColA2019" "ColB2019" "ColC2019" "ColA2020" "ColB2020" "ColC2020"

periodo <- 2019

patrón <- (paste("ID", "\\|", periodo, sep=""))
df = subset (df, select=_condición_)

colnames(df)
# "ID" "ColA2019" "ColB2019" "ColC2019"
```

Es decir, seleccionando la columna "ID" y las columnas según el periodo que incorporan a sus nombres, el propósito es hacer reproducible y automático un informe.

Gracias.
José Carlos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para este caso te recomiendo usar la función `select()` del paquete `dplyr` en lugar de `subset()`, porque permite usar patrones de manera muy sencilla para nombres de columnas.

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- structure(list(ID = 1, ColA2019 = 1, ColB2019 = 1, ColC2019 = 1, 
                     ColA2020 = 1, ColB2020 = 1, ColC2020 = 1), 
                row.names = c(NA, -1L), 
                class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

colnames(df)
#> [1] "ID"       "ColA2019" "ColB2019" "ColC2019" "ColA2020" "ColB2020" "ColC2020"

df <- select(df, ID, contains("2019"))

colnames(df)
#> [1] "ID"       "ColA2019" "ColB2019" "ColC2019"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado otra solución con R base:

```
periodo <- "2019"
patrón <- (paste("ID", "\\|", periodo, sep=""))
columnas <- grep(patrón, colnames(df), value=T) 
df <- subset(df, select=columnas)
```